# How can i join this 2 MySQL queries together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have query that pulls in some products there are many products and the list will grow

```
SELECT pid, link, created_at FROM products ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

But I also have another table which contains a `pid` and `rating` field, the `pid` is the link to the products table.

```
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ratings GROUP BY pid
```

How can i query so it will pull out the information like below?

```
products.pid, products.link, products.created_at, AVG(ratings.rating)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, this should give the result you want;

```sql
SELECT p.pid, p.link, p.created_at, AVG(r.rating) rating
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN ratings r
  ON p.pid=r.pid
GROUP BY p.pid;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c99e9/3).

As a side note, MySQL is special since it lets you do incomplete `GROUP BY` queries, so if you want to run it on another database (or maybe for stylistic reasons), the query should instead be;

```sql
SELECT p.pid, p.link, p.created_at, AVG(r.rating) rating
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN ratings r
  ON p.pid=r.pid
GROUP BY p.pid, p.link, p.created_at;
```

Comment: You can also avoid the incomplete `GROUP BY` if you use the subquery method in my answer. I think it may also be more efficient, since grouping before joining means the temporary table from the join is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

In MS-SQL it's possible to select this as:

```
SELECT p.pid, 
       p.link, 
       p.created_at, 
       (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ratings r where r.pid = p.pid) as rating
  FROM products p
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Question is about MySQL, not MSSQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551312/mysql-nested-query-select-statement 
Here is another example of this as done in mysql.
both are based on SQL and such common concepts are usually transferable.

Comment: Concept is the same. Query may need a few tweaks, but [sub-queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) exist in MySQL as well

Comment: The concepts are often the same, but the details may differ. Someone who doesn't know how to write a simple join probably won't be able to do the conversion. Also, performance issues vary, so the preferred method is very dependent on the database.

Comment: I agree that each SQL database system has a varying implementation of the standard. But in this case the solution did work. The better solution would be the one above which used an inner join rather than a sub select though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.pid, link, created_at, avg_rating
FROM products p
JOIN (SELECT pid, AVG(rating) avg_rating
      FROM ratings
      GROUP BY pid) a
ON p.pid = a.pid
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used the other posts above, it always showed this error to me:

```
'Unknown column "timestamp" in "order clause"'
```

I believe that the timestamp is added to the created_at column in the products table. So, I have used the ordering on this column itself. It will pick the last row from the product table and print the AVG(rating) with it.

```
SELECT products.pid, products.link, products.created_at, AVG(ratings.rating)
FROM products, ratings
WHERE products.pid = ratings.pid
GROUP BY products.pid
ORDER BY products.created_at ASC
;
```

This query is tested and working fine for me.